# Jquery: firefox not support unload function

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

here its my jquery code

```
$(window).unload(function(){
     chat_leave()
});
```

I want to run following function on window unload. but its not work in firefox.

```
function chat_leave() {
$http.post('/chat/leave/',{chatIdList:$scope.chat_room_id}).then(function (response) {});
}
```

Above jquery code work perfect in chrome but not in firefox is there any another solution for above query.

Comment: And what does `chat_leave` do ?

Comment: `$http.post('/chat/leave/',{chatIdList:$scope.chat_room_id}).then(function (response) {});`

Comment: Doing a complex function like an AJAX call in an unload event is unreliable at best. The better way to handle this is to have a "heartbeat" AJAX call that lets the server know the client is still there. When the client does not respond after a while then they can be interpreted as "being offline".

Comment: So it's something asynchronous? The `unload` handler is notoriously unreliable, as there's no guarantee that anything will be executed before the browser has time to shut down the page, and that goes especially for async functions.